# Undesired deletion of temporaly files

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am try to create some temporal files and make some operations on them inside a loop. Then I will access the information on **all** of the temporal files. And do some operations with that information. For simplicity I brought the following code that reproduces my issue:

```
import tempfile
tmp_files = []
for i in range(40):
    tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt")
    with open(tmp.name, "w") as f:
        f.write(str(i))
    tmp_files.append(tmp.name)

string = ""
for tmp_file in tmp_files:
    with open(tmp_file, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    string += data
print(string)
```

ERROR:

```
 with open(tmp_file, "r") as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpynh0kbnw.txt'
```

When I look on **/tmp** directory (with some time.sleep(2) on the loop) I see that the file is deleted and only one is preserved. And for that the error.
Of course I could handle to keep all the files with the flag `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt", delete=False)`. But that is not the idea. I would like to hold the temporal files just for the running time of the script. I also could delete the files with os.remove. But my question is more why this happen. Because I expected that the files hold to the end of the running. Because I don't close the file on the execution (or do I?).
A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: When the `with open...` block ends, the file is closed automatically.

Comment: But if `with open` statement close the file, how this code works?
```
a = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(a.name, "w") as f:
f.write("Hello")
b = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(b.name, "w") as f:
f.write(" World!")

string = ""
with open(a.name, "r") as f:
string += f.read()
with open(b.name, "r") as f:
string += f.read()

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tdelaney does already answer your actual question.

I just would like to offer you an alternative to `NamedTemporaryFile`. Why not creating a temporary folder which is removed (with all files in it) at the end of the script?

---

Instead of using a `NamedTemporaryFile`, you could use [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory). The directory will be deleted when closed.

The example below uses the `with` statement which closes the file handle automatically when the block ends (see John Gordon's comment).

```py
import os
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_folder:
    
    tmp_files = []

    for i in range(40):
        tmp_file = os.path.join(temp_folder, f"{i}.txt")
        with open(tmp_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(str(i))
        tmp_files.append(tmp_file)

    string = ""
    for tmp_file in tmp_files:
        with open(tmp_file, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
        string += data

    print(string)
```

Comment: It really helps me. Also I see that it is possible without the `with` statment. Just: `tmp_folder = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()`, and then just `tmp_file = os.path.join(temp_folder.name, f"{i}.txt")`. And in this way you could hold the temporal directory for future use in the code, without the necesity of the `with`. But this is jut another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `NamedTemporaryFile` deletes its file when closed. its a bit subtle, but `tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt")` in the loop causes the previous file to be deleted when `tmp` is reassigned. One option is to use the `delete=False` parameter. Or, just keep the file open and `seek` to the beginning after the write.

`NamedTemporaryFile` is already a file object - you can write to it directly without reopening. Just make sure the mode is "write plus" and in text, not binary mode. Put the code an a try/finally block to make sure the files are really deleted at the end.

```
import tempfile
tmp_files = []
try:
    for i in range(40):
        tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt", mode="w+")
        tmp.write(str(i))
        tmp.seek(0)
        tmp_files.append(tmp)

    string = ""
    for tmp_file in tmp_files:
        data = tmp_file.read()
        string += data
finally:
    for tmp_file in tmp_files:
        tmp_file.close()
print(string)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the your answer, it helps me a lot! But the oversimplification of my problem with the example that I gave hide some other stuffs on my code. But in fact, your answer is what I exactly ask in my question. However the answer of @Thomas is more suitable for my general problem (not presented in the question), and, of course, answer also the question that I asked.